# how do I get the string to the right side of a character?

Tags: c#, string

```
connectionString=Data Source=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=DATABASE1;Integrated Security=True
```

I want to capture EVERYTHING to the right of "=".

How would I go about doing this?

```
Console.WriteLine(connectionString);

Data Source=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=DATABASE1;Integrated Security=True
```

I tried:

```
variable = string.Split('=')[1]
```

but it only gives me "Data Source"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var str = "connectionString=Data Source=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=DATABASE1;Integrated Security=True";
var res = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('=')+1);
```

Note that of there is no `'='` character in the string, the entire string will be returned. If there are multiple `'='` characters present, the first character will be used as the "cutting point", and the remaining ones will be ignored.

[Link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/IfL9iY).

Comment: I think we answered within <1 second from each other :-)

Comment: @JuliánUrbano That's true - this happens often on relatively straightforward questions.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the position of the first `=` and then take everything from there:

```
string s = "connectionString=Data Source=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=DATABASE1;Integrated Security=True";
int position = s.IndexOf('=');
string rest = s.Substring(position + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Substring(yourstring.IndexOf('='))
```

It gets the first index of the = sign and then substrings everything to the right.